# An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll (C#, VisualStudio 2015)

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

(Buttons and other private voids are above this.)

```
private int caseSwitch = 0;
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    caseSwitch++;
    switch (caseSwitch)
    {
        case 1:
            BackgroundImage = new Bitmap("PT-AFD background1.bmp");
            break;
        case 2:
            BackgroundImage = new Bitmap("PT-AFD background2.bmp");
            break;
        case 3:
            BackgroundImage = new Bitmap("PT-AFD background3.bmp");
            break;
        case 4:
            BackgroundImage = new Bitmap("PT-AFD background4.bmp");
            break;
        case 5:
            caseSwitch = 0;
            break;
    }
```

After thorough testing I have exhausted my knowledge, the only thing I've been able to ascertain is that the error fires when it reaches the end of the 'new Bitmap' lines.

Any suggestions? Everything I've found on this error is extremely vague or just doesn't apply to my situation.

Comment: Are those files in your bin folder?

Comment: Any special BMP sub-format? Does any image ever show? How fast is the Timer? Do you ever dispose of the images? Why don't you cache them?

Comment: try to rename "PT-AFD background1.bmp" to "1.bmp" and rename others also...

Answer (score 0):

Alright, this was a brainfart on my behalf.

@CodingYoshi suggested I check to make sure that the files were in my bin folder and I at first thought this was too obvious to be the problem and distinctly remembered putting them there. The issue was that I coded them as BMPs, but the versions of the images in the bin folder were older jpgs and I'd accidentally been saving the newer versions to the project root.

Thanks guys, sorry the answer was so simple. m(_ _)m